# How to extract the values from a nested array into another array

Tags: php

This is the array I want to extract from:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 11
                [order_id] => 6127
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 12
                [order_id] => 6123
            )

    )
```

This is what I need:

```
$results = array()
$results(6127, 6123)
```

There can be any number of arrays within the first array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through the array then add the order ids to another array:

```
$results = array();
foreach($arr as $item)
{
    $results[] = $item['order_id'];
}
```

Comment: @Patrick:  It's that 4th line of code:  `$results[] = $item['order_id'];` -- `$item['order_id']` is added as a new item to the array `$results`.

Comment: gotcha.  thank you.  I'm still learning.  I struggle with arrays.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Make use of array_map:

```
$result = array_map(function($el) {
    return $el['order_id'];
}, $arr);
```

Or for PHP version prior to 5.3:

```
$result = array_map(create_function('$el', 'return $el["order_id"];'), $arr);
```